# How to define a multidimensional array in Java using curly braces?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't understand the behaviour of Java about arrays. It forbids to define an array in one case but allows the same definition in another.

The example from tutorial:

```
String[][] names = {
        {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "},
        {"Smith", "Jones"}
    };
System.out.println(names[0][0] + names[1][0]);    // the output is "Mr. Smith";
```

My example:

```
public class User {
   private static String[][] users;
   private static int UC = 0;

   public void addUser (String email, String name, String pass) {
      int i = 0;

      // Here, when I define an array this way, it has no errors in NetBeans
      String[][] u = { {email, name, pass}, {"one@one.com", "jack sparrow", "12345"} };

      // But when I try to define like this, using static variable users declared above, NetBeans throws errors
      if (users == null) {
         users = { { email, name, pass }, {"one", "two", "three"} };    // NetBeans even doesn't recognize arguments 'email', 'name', 'pass' here. Why?

         // only this way works
         users = new String[3][3];
         users[i][i] = email;
         users[i][i+1] = name;
         users[i][i+2] = pass;
         UC = UC + 1;
      }
    }
```

The mistakes thrown by NetBeans are:

*illegal start of expression,*

*";" expected*,

*not a statement*.

And also it doesn't recognize arguments `email`, `name`, `pass` in the definition of the `users` array. But recognizes them when I define `u` array.

What is the difference between these two definitions? Why the one works but the another one defined the same way doesn't?

Answer (score 12):

You need to add `new String[][]` before the array aggregate:

```
users = new String[][] { { email, name, pass }, {"one", "two", "three"} };
```

Comment: But I have done this already. Right below the line of "public class User {" is the line "private static String[][] users"

Comment: @Green The `new String[][]` part is implied when you combine initialization and declaration; when you declare a field or a variable in one place, but initialize it in a different place, you need to explicitly provide the type of the object that you are creating before the array aggregate.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this syntax:

```
String[][] u = {{email, name, pass}, {"one@one.com", "jack sparrow", "12345"}};
```

*Only* when you're declaring the matrix for the first time. It won't work for assigning values to a `String[][]` variable *after* you've declared it elsewhere, that's why `users = ...` fails. For assigning values to an already-declared `String[][]` (or a matrix of any other type for that matter), use

```
users = new String[][] { { email, name, pass }, {"one", "two", "three"} };
```

Answer (score 2):

The first case is an initialization statement, while the second is only an assignment. That kind of filling arrays is only supported when defining a new array.

Answer (score 2):

For re-assigning the matrix you must use `new`:

```
users = new String[][] {{email, name, pass }, {"one", "two", "three"}};
```